# esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino-esp8266, adafruit

I'm having trouble loading code into my ESP8266 board. The error msg was posted below. Note that my board was working a year ago.

> Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266, 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (1M SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
>
> Sketch uses 257696 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
>   Global variables use 26572 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55348 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
>
> esptool.py v2.6
>
> 2.6
>
> esptool.py v2.6
>
> Serial port COM8
>
> Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Owen\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2/tools/upload.py", line 25, in 
>       esptool.main(fakeargs)
>     File 
>   "C:/Users/Owen/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2653, in main
>       esp.connect(args.before)
>     File "C:/Users/Owen/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 468, in connect
>       raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
>
> esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
>
> esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

_

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this problem.

- 1st proposal: the esp and the attached sensors etc. are consuming to much power. Detach the sensors and try to upload the sketch again. Or make sure, that you esp is getting enough power. (You could also try another micro-usb cable / power source)
- 2ns proposal: change the baudrate.
- 3rd proposal: If you connected an micro SD shield, detach the microSD card and try again.

These have been the cases, when I ran over this issue. I hope one of those guesses is going to help you.